# Next.js on multiple cores using Docker

Tags: node.js, docker, next.js, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I have a Next.js web app (SSG and SSR) deployed on a VPS with 6 CPU cores.

The application is dockerized and managed through a Docker Compose stack. It's behind Traefik as a reverse-proxy.

Something like:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  website:
    image: ghcr.io/.../my-website-image
    container_name: website
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    labels:
        - traefik-labels
        - [...]
    networks:
      - proxy

networks:
  proxy:
    external: true
```

This setup is fairly straight-forward and works great! However, I've been wondering how I could utilize the multiple CPU cores of my machine to scale my Next.js app a little.

I've heard about options like [pm2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/) that utilize Node.js clustering. However, I've been wondering if there's a somewhat simple way to make use of my already existing Docker setup to spin up multiple containers running my Next.js app maybe and load-balance between them somehow?

I'd really appreciate some advice on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify how many application replicas you want to deploy (example):

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  website:
    image: ghcr.io/.../my-website-image
    container_name: website
    restart: unless-stopped
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 3
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    labels:
        - traefik-labels
        - [...]
    networks:
      - proxy

networks:
  proxy:
    external: true
```

And then, for example, add NGINX service, where to configure the balancer to distribute the load between your replicas. :)

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that works in Compose too!